# Can you say 'until eternity'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> I wish I had a public transport ticket valid until eternity.

In general, if you refer to something that is supposed to last forever, can you use *until eternity* or is there a better expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say "*until* eternity" because eternity is the *period* of time starting now and continuing without end (or arguably until the end of the universe). You could therefore say "*for* eternity".

Alternatives would be "forever", "forevermore", "forever and ever" or "until the end of time".

Or you could take a slightly different approach and just say "that never expires".